# How do i stop slider if there one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am new in jquery, i found a slider from [http://idangero.us/swiper/](https://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/hg9pane2/4/)

its working fine, But the client requirement is if there is only one image on the slider will stop its slide functionality and hide navigation automatically.

Anyone can solve this issue i will be much appreciated.

Fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/hg9pane2/4/)

Thanks

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  slideWidth: 268,
  slideHeight: 268,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 12,
});
```

```css
/**
 * Swiper 3.3.0
 * Most modern mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions
 * 
 * http://www.idangero.us/swiper/
 * 
 * Copyright 2016, Vladimir Kharlampidi
 * The iDangero.us
 * http://www.idangero.us/
 * 
 * Licensed under MIT
 * 
 * Released on: January 10, 2016
 */
.swiper-outter-container { width:300px; position:relative;}
.swiper-container{margin:0 auto;position:relative;overflow:hidden;z-index:1}.swiper-container-no-flexbox .swiper-slide{float:left}.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-wrapper{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-moz-box-orient:vertical;-ms-flex-direction:column;-webkit-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.swiper-wrapper{position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform;transition-property:transform;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}.swiper-container-android .swiper-slide,.swiper-wrapper{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-o-transform:translate(0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}.swiper-container-multirow>.swiper-wrapper{-webkit-box-lines:multiple;-moz-box-lines:multiple;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;-webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap}.swiper-container-free-mode>.swiper-wrapper{-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-moz-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-ms-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-o-transition-timing-function:ease-out;transition-timing-function:ease-out;margin:0 auto}.swiper-slide{-webkit-flex-shrink:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex-shrink:0;width:100%;height:100%;position:relative}.swiper-container-autoheight,.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-slide{height:auto}.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-wrapper{-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;-webkit-align-items:flex-start;align-items:flex-start;-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform,height;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform;transition-property:transform,height}.swiper-container .swiper-notification{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;pointer-events:none;opacity:0;z-index:-1000}.swiper-wp8-horizontal{-ms-touch-action:pan-y;touch-action:pan-y}.swiper-wp8-vertical{-ms-touch-action:pan-x;touch-action:pan-x}.swiper-button-next,.swiper-button-prev{position:absolute;top:50%;width:27px;height:44px;margin-top:-22px;z-index:10;cursor:pointer;-moz-background-size:27px 44px;-webkit-background-size:27px 44px;background-size:27px 44px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat}.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled,.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled{opacity:.35;cursor:auto;pointer-events:none}.swiper-button-prev,.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");left:10px;right:auto}.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black,.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")}.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white,.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")}.swiper-button-next,.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");right:10px;left:auto}.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black,.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")}.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white,.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")}.swiper-pagination{position:absolute;text-align:center;-webkit-transition:.3s;-moz-transition:.3s;-o-transition:.3s;transition:.3s;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);z-index:10}.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden{opacity:0}.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,.swiper-pagination-custom,.swiper-pagination-fraction{bottom:10px;left:0;width:100%}.swiper-pagination-bullet{width:8px;height:8px;display:inline-block;border-radius:100%;background:#000;opacity:.2}button.swiper-pagination-bullet{border:none;margin:0;padding:0;box-shadow:none;-moz-appearance:none;-ms-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;appearance:none}.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet{cursor:pointer}.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet{background:#fff}.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{opacity:1;background:#007aff}.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{background:#fff}.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{background:#000}.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets{right:10px;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);-o-transform:translate(0,-50%);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0)}.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet{margin:5px 0;display:block}.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet{margin:0 5px}.swiper-pagination-progress{background:rgba(0,0,0,.25);position:absolute}.swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar{background:#007aff;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;-webkit-transform:scale(0);-ms-transform:scale(0);-o-transform:scale(0);transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform-origin:left top;-moz-transform-origin:left top;-ms-transform-origin:left top;-o-transform-origin:left top;transform-origin:left top}.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar{-webkit-transform-origin:right top;-moz-transform-origin:right top;-ms-transform-origin:right top;-o-transform-origin:right top;transform-origin:right top}.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progress{width:100%;height:4px;left:0;top:0}.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progress{width:4px;height:100%;left:0;top:0}.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white{background:rgba(255,255,255,.5)}.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-progressbar{background:#fff}.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-progressbar{background:#000}.swiper-container-3d{-webkit-perspective:1200px;-moz-perspective:1200px;-o-perspective:1200px;perspective:1200px}.swiper-container-3d .swiper-cube-shadow,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-wrapper{-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;-moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;-ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;transform-style:preserve-3d}.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;pointer-events:none;z-index:10}.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0))}.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0))}.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-o-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0))}.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,0))}.swiper-container-coverflow .swiper-wrapper,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-wrapper{-ms-perspective:1200px}.swiper-container-cube,.swiper-container-flip{overflow:visible}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide{pointer-events:none;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;backface-visibility:hidden;z-index:1}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide{pointer-events:none}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active{pointer-events:auto}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-left,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-right,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-top,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-left,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-right,.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-top{z-index:0;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;backface-visibility:hidden}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide{visibility:hidden;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;-moz-transform-origin:0 0;-ms-transform-origin:0 0;transform-origin:0 0;width:100%;height:100%}.swiper-container-cube.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-slide{-webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;-moz-transform-origin:100% 0;-ms-transform-origin:100% 0;transform-origin:100% 0}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide,.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-prev{pointer-events:auto;visibility:visible}.swiper-container-cube .swiper-cube-shadow{position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:#000;opacity:.6;-webkit-filter:blur(50px);filter:blur(50px);z-index:0}.swiper-container-fade.swiper-container-free-mode .swiper-slide{-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-moz-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-ms-transition-timing-function:ease-out;-o-transition-timing-function:ease-out;transition-timing-function:ease-out}.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide{pointer-events:none;-webkit-transition-property:opacity;-moz-transition-property:opacity;-o-transition-property:opacity;transition-property:opacity}.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide{pointer-events:none}.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active,.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active{pointer-events:auto}.swiper-scrollbar{border-radius:10px;position:relative;-ms-touch-action:none;background:rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-scrollbar{position:absolute;left:1%;bottom:3px;z-index:50;height:5px;width:98%}.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-scrollbar{position:absolute;right:3px;top:1%;z-index:50;width:5px;height:98%}.swiper-scrollbar-drag{height:100%;width:100%;position:relative;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);border-radius:10px;left:0;top:0}.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag{cursor:move}.swiper-lazy-preloader{width:42px;height:42px;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-left:-21px;margin-top:-21px;z-index:10;-webkit-transform-origin:50%;-moz-transform-origin:50%;transform-origin:50%;-webkit-animation:swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12,end) infinite;-moz-animation:swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12,end) infinite;animation:swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12,end) infinite}.swiper-lazy-preloader:after{display:block;content:"";width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%236c6c6c'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");background-position:50%;-webkit-background-size:100%;background-size:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat}.swiper-lazy-preloader-white:after{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%23fff'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")}@-webkit-keyframes swiper-preloader-spin{100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin{100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>


<div class="swiper-outter-container">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="http://modelshop.co.uk/Content/DynamicMedia/Items/DetailsPage/9235_Image.jpg" alt="box1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the number of slides using jquery. If it's 1 then use `swiper` object's `destroy` method to disable the slider. And also hide the `next` and `previous` buttons.

```
if($(".swiper-slide").length === 1){
    swiper.destroy();
  $(".swiper-button").css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much...Its work...exactly i want to do like this. @ShwethaU

Comment: i have to make there is some change,  i want to fix  ''if there are at least 2 slides and only then apply slideshow functionality''.) @ShwethaU

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.swiper-image .swiper-slide').length < 2){ //if length of images less 2
  swiper.stopAutoplay();  //stop autoplay | http://idangero.us/swiper/api/
  $('.swiper-button').hide(); //hide buttons
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some extra explaination outside of the code comments itself to make your answer better.

Comment: Thanks for a response

Answer (score 0):

Count the no of images first.

```
var numImage = $('.swiper-slide').length;
if(numImage == 1){
// Write your code without slider
}else{
// Your code with slider.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a response